# double series and integral resulting in an indetermined answer

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, fractions

I have the following:

$$P = \sum_{j=1}^{6} \sum_{k=1}^{6} A(k,j) \int_0^h e^{(\alpha^{(k)} -\overline\alpha^{(j)})x} dx$$

Where A is a constant that depends on $j$ and $k$. Taking the integral yields:

$$P = \sum_{j=1}^{6} \sum_{k=1}^{6} A(k,j) \frac{1}{(\alpha^{(k)} -\overline\alpha^{(j)})} e^{(\alpha^{(k)} -\overline\alpha^{(j)})x} \bigg\vert_0^h$$

Where $\alpha$ is either pure real or pure imaginary and $\alpha_{2n} = -\alpha_{2n-1}$ $n=1,2,3$. For certain combinations of $j$ and $k$ the denominator $(\alpha^{(k)} -\overline\alpha^{(j)})$ and numerator $e^{(\alpha^{(k)} -\overline\alpha^{(j)})x} \bigg\vert_0^h$ will equal to zero, resulting in $\frac{0}{0}$.

The question is how can I justify that $P$ will equal to zero (is it even possible?), or do I need to apply l'Hopital's rule?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You aren't taking a limit, so L'Hopital's rule has nothing to do with this problem. Without knowing something about the values $A(k,j)$, this cannot be proven. Suppose that for some given values of $A(k,j)$ you do have $P$ equals $0$. But at least some of the integrals for particular values of $k,j$ will be non-zero. If you increase the value of $A(k,j)$ for just one $k, j$ with a non-zero integral while leaving $A(k,j)$ unchanged for all other $k,j$, then $P$ will no longer be $0$. Thus this cannot be true for all possible $A(k,j)$.

Comment: A is a constant always greater than zero that will vary with $j$ and $k$. Are there any other mathematical theorems that can be applied to avoid 0/0 or define P when 0/0 obtained. 0/0 will occur for some $\alpha^k$ and $\alpha^j$ combinations

Comment: I read your description of $A$ already. It doesn't specify the exact values $A$ takes on for various $k, j$. And as I described already, it is those exact values that will determine whether this $P = 0$ or not. As for your $\frac 00$ problem, your formula for the value of the integral doesn't hold when $\alpha^{(k)} =\overline\alpha^{(j)}$. However, the integral is even more easily integrated in that case.